# Unsupported clipboard format when pasting PNG/JPG files

Tags: delphi, clipboard, pascal

I'm coding a unit where I can paste an image from the clipboard and save it in a DB. The code actually works if I took screenshots or copy images from WhatsApp/Telegram Web.

But the problems appears when I try to paste a PNG or JPG **file** from the clipboard - the error message is:

> Unsupported clipboard format

Why does this code work with screenshots but not with PNG or JPG files? How can I fix it?

```
BMP := TBitmap.Create;
BMP.Assign(Clipboard);      //Here is where I got the exception
BMP.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
JPG.Assign(BMP);
JPG.CompressionQuality := 75;
AdvOfficeImage1.Picture.Assign(JPG);
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread your Q. The clipboard contains a *file name*, not an *image*. Then I suspect it will not work with a BMP image either.

Comment: But if I assign the clipboard directly to the TJPEGImage variable i get the another exception: "Cannot assign a TClipboard to a TJPEGImage".

Comment: Probably you just have to detect that the clipboard contains a file and then load the file in code.

Comment: Here's a very helpful utility you can use to see what's actually in your clipboard: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you copy a file from the shell, the clipboard will not contain the contents of the file, but merely the file name.

Hence, you need to obtain this file name, and then use it to load your image.

Here's a small example, just containing a `TImage` control:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_HDROP) then
  begin

    Clipboard.Open;
    try
      var LDrop := Clipboard.GetAsHandle(CF_HDROP);
      if LDrop <> 0 then
      begin
        var LFileCount := DragQueryFile(LDrop, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);
        if LFileCount = 1 then
        begin
          var LSize := DragQueryFile(LDrop, 0, nil, 0);
          if LSize <> 0 then
          begin
            var LFileName: string;
            SetLength(LFileName, LSize);
            if DragQueryFile(LDrop, 0, PChar(LFileName), LFileName.Length + 1) <> 0 then
              Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(LFileName);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Clipboard.Close;
    end;

  end;

end;
```

Note: `Clipboard` is declared in `Clipbrd` and `DragQueryFile` in `ShellAPI`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! This works perfect. I would never have fixed it.

Just so you know, how did you know that the CF_HDROP format means it's a file? Is there a table where the different formats of the clipboard can be consulted?

Thanks again for your help, it was very useful for me.

Comment: @Julian `CF_HDROP` is a predefined clipboard format provided by Windows, see [Standard Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) and [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard) on MSDN